# No module named "..."

Tags: python, module

Recently i've got these error

I tried pip update and everything but it doesnt work

the code ran completely fine, until i reset my computer and reinstall python then this happened.

```
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\Code\Custom project\Assistant_projct\main.pyw", line 11, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk,Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Folders\Code\Games\pygame\1\Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame, sys # import pygame and sys
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Is your desktop environment cinnamon ? I've had a similar issue with PIL a while ago that was related to cinnamon

Comment: have you setup python path in environment varible with script path too!

Comment: If you reinstalled Python, you will need to also reinstall all the third-party modules you want to use.

Comment: Hi, well I found that it can run perfectly on python IDLE but not visual studio....